# Jquery- Dynamic added fields - prevent the last Item to be removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I have a form field that is being duplicated / removed  dynamically

See the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/y2d4c/6/

In this feature, I also need to increment the NAME of the field ( and ID etc.. ) like so :

```
o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content][0]
o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content][1]
o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content][2] ...
```

It is working, but the problem is that when I add / remove fields , when it gets to the last ( actually first one ) , it will give me "undefined" and will not add anymore fields .

To see the problem you will need to "play" a bit with add/remove .

I believe the main problem is how to keep all of those on the same array level if we have [0] and [0][2]

I am far from a JS guru, and this code was somehow assembled from various sources. But I am kind of stuck right now, So any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Check for the elements collection `length` before removing.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - ,.. And how would I do that ?

Comment: I've posted an answer. Note that you don't need to keep track of the variable `i` to always know how many elements are already present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(function () {
    $(".addScnt").on("click", function () {
        var i = checkNumberOfElements();
        var scntDiv = $("div[id^='widget_dup']:last");
        var prevDiv = scntDiv.clone();
        var newname = $(prevDiv).find("textarea").attr("name").substring(0, $(prevDiv).find("textarea").attr('name').indexOf(']'));

        prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('name', newname + "][" + i + "]");
        prevDiv.find('textarea').attr('id', newname + "][" + i + "]");
        prevDiv.find('label').attr('for', newname + "][" + i + "]");
        prevDiv.attr('id', $(prevDiv).attr('id') + "_" + i);

        $(scntDiv).after(prevDiv);
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".remScnt", function (event) {
        var i = checkNumberOfElements();

        if (i <= 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            var target = $(event.currentTarget);
            target.parent("div").remove();
        }
    });
});

function checkNumberOfElements() {
    // Number of textareas
    var i = $("textarea[name^='o99_brsa_settings[brsa_dash_wdgt_content]']").length;
    // Number of divs
    // var i = $("div[id^='widget_dup']").length;

    if (typeof i === undefined) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y2d4c/7/

Comment: after implementing and checking again, there is a small problem . if removing and adding a field repeatedly - the ID (of the widget ) will become `widget_dup_1_2_2_2_2` or `widget_dup_1_2_3_4_5` - which will break the code ...

Comment: This bit is part of your previous code. It's where you are generating the new ID. `prevDiv.attr('id', $(prevDiv).attr('id') + "_" + i);` You should use the same "formula" you're using with the textareas.

Comment: right.. I figured that out as soon as I wrote the comment ... Sorry , My JS is notoriously and apparently hopelessly bad . somehow my PHP skills and my JS are bound to be perfect opposite pair where any increase in one ( PHP ) subtracts something from the JS . Someone should study this phenomena :-)

Comment: No problems. I've been there once. :)